# Pairwise corelation Plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have dataframe In R wanted to plot pairwise corelation plot currently using package "PerformanceAnalytics" but I am not able get nice colored graph any one suggest me a nice package i tried "psych" not able install to my system. is there any way i can plot
below mention my data

```
 test1  test2   test3   test4   test4   test5   test6   test7
1.4367  1.6589  2.0227  2.2793  159.91  144     18910.1 19137.1902803603
0.2403  0.3404  0.9538  1.1041  226.1   317.61  6275.68 12618.0982994217
0.1737  0.2882  0.8039  3.1088  372.12  177.59  7912.73 6529.72939693551
```

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")

chart.Correlation(df, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

output[image]

how I wanted a nice colured plot like below any one suggest me how can I plot[image]

Comment: Try [ggally::ggpair](https://cran.r-project.org/package=GGally) or [corrplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html)

Comment: @zx8754 Okay Thank you